# Knockout applyBindingsToNode issue for composite observables condition

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding

I am using knockout and I am applying runtime programatically a binding to a certain node using ko.applyBindingstoNode.

The first, simple case works:

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(myElement, {visible: observable1}, myModel );
```

But if my visible depends on more observable, and I use normal notation as if I was binding via html data-bind attribute, it do not work:

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(myElement, {visible: observable1() && observable2()}, myModel );
```

I needed to define a ko.computed and use it in programmatical binding, but i do realy do not want to create theese computeds, because I am worried about the performance for older browsers, like IE6

How can be done with applyBindingsToNode a binding that involves complex expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want a computed-value without using a computed? That is not possible, you need to use ko.computed:

```
var myComputed = ko.computed(function(){
    return observable1() && observable2();
});

ko.applyBindingsToNode(myElement, {visible: myComputed}, myModel);
```

If you were to do this in HTML, it would create a computed in the background anyway.

Knockout performance is quite good. If you're really worried you should do a benchmark and check whether it really matters

Comment: So, the argument of a binding is, explicitly or implicitly, always an observable (possibly computed)? And this becomes evident in the direct use of the function applyBindingsToNode, am I correct?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a computed, you could also bind a regular value, but then it won't get updated when the value changes. it's just that when you apply a binding in HTML with an expression, I suppose knockout wraps it in a computed. There's no other way that would work otherwise.

Comment: where from myElement, myModel are coming